# using |= in php

Tags: php, equality

I was reading some php code source and found the following:

```
$failed |= is_numeric( $key );
```

Other than if `$key` is numeric , what does `|=` mean?

Comment: http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.assignment.php#40084

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`$x |= $y;` is the same as `$x = $x | $y;`

`$x | $y` is a bitwise operator which means it returns the result of a logical 'or' between the two variables.

In the context of the question, it allows `$failed` to store failure statuses for several actions in a single variable (each bit position representing an individual action).

If you need to know more about what this does, I suggest reading the PHP manual page for bitwise operators: http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.bitwise.php

Comment: +1 for being the most correct and most complete answer thus far.

Comment: Voting is not for comparisons with other answers, but for absolute value. Still, +1 because this is a good answer.

Answer (score 12):

The notation `$a |= $b` means `$a = $a | $b`, similar to other `x=` notations.  The `|` is a bitwise OR operation.

Answer (score 4):

It's the equivalent of:

```
$failed = $failed | is_numeric($key);
```

`|` is the bitwise `or` operator.

Anytime you see `x <something>= y`, it can be rewritten as `x = x <something> y`, pretty much.

Answer (score 4):

That's a bitwise `OR` so the line is the same as

```
$failed = $failed | is_numeric($key);
```

That means `$failed` is `true` if either `$failed` has been `true` before **or** `is_numeric($key)` is `true`.